# removeEventListener using the EventTarget

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array with the button objects.
When it is clicked, it gets the "button-active" tag and
when it is clicked again, it removes the "button-active" class

I want to removeEventListener when flag is true

```
let flag = false;

const buttonActive = () => {
    arr.forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener("click", function eventListener(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            if(checkClass(e, "button-active")) removeClass(e, "button-active")
            else addClass(e, "button-active")
        })
    })
}

button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let input = document.createElement('div')
    input.className = "info"
    input.innerHTML += `...(some html with buttons that have weekday class)...`
    info.appendChild(input)
    flag = true;
    arr = document.querySelectorAll('.weekday')
    buttonActive()
})
```

I thought of a way of putting the eventListener function outside the buttonActive function, but the eventListener function uses the variable e.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: can you explain the purpose of the `flag` because you easily `remove Listener` using simple code after clicking or based on `class`?

Answer (score 0):

simple~

```js
let flag = false;
let cbs = [];

const buttonActive = (arr, active) => {
    if (active) {
        cbs = arr.map(e => {
            const cb = (event) => {
                event.preventDefault()
                if(checkClass(e, "button-active")) removeClass(e, "button-active")
                else addClass(e, "button-active")
            }
            e.addEventListener("click", cb)
            return cb;
        });
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            arr[i].removeEventListener('click', cbs[i]);
        }
    }
}

// I guess this is the trigger button
button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let input = document.createElement('div')
    input.className = "info"
    input.innerHTML += `...(some html with buttons that have weekday class)...`
    info.appendChild(input)
    flag = !!flag;
    arr = document.querySelectorAll('.weekday')
    buttonActive(arr, flag)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to removeEventListener when flag variable is true

Comment: @genius I don't find any variable named `flag`.

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote this question

Comment: @genius I don't know what you mean. You said you want to  removeEventListener when flag variable is true, but there is no variable named flag at all. As a result, No one know what flag is except you.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I wrote a question on stack overflow